# Babel not transpiling ES6 computed property names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-cli

Babel is not transpiling ES6 computed property names. It compiles everything else though. Not sure what's going on. Using the latest version of cli.

```
var name = "John"; 
var age = 12; 
var count = 5; 
var postfix = 'age';

var person = {
    name, 
    age, 
    count,
    postfix,
    printName(){
        console.log(this.name); 
        this.count--; 
        while(this.count){
            this.printName(); 
        }
    },

    ['print' + this.postfix]: function(){
        console.log(this.age);
    }
};

person.printName(); 
person.printAge();
```

**Babel output**

```
var name = "John";
var age = 12;
var count = 5;
var postfix = 'age';

var person = _defineProperty({
    name: name,
    age: age,
    count: count,
    postfix: postfix,
    printName: function printName() {
        console.log(this.name);
        this.count--;
        while (this.count) {
            this.printName();
        }
    }
}, 'print' + postfix, function () { // Look here
    console.log(this.age);
});
```

Comment: Looks like it gets correctly transpiled, resulting function name would be `printage()`, but you are trying to access it using `printAge()`, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: You code samples also don't match up. The first uses `this.postfix` and the second uses `postfix` as the property name. I'll second @Stubb0rn though, you'd need `person.printage();`

Comment: Seems like it was my error + some confusion. I thought it would be converted to the computed value instead of 'print' + postfix.

Comment: It **was** converted to the computed value which **was** `'print' + postfix`.

Comment: yes (hence the confusion part of my comment). I actually thought it would be computed to printAge.

Answer (score 3):

In what sense is it not transpiling computed property names? That looks exactly correct to me.

Are you referring to the fact that it dropped the `this` before `postfix`? That's because they're the same - `this` in a computed property name in ES6 does not refer to the object, and instead is whatever it would be outside the object. Here that's the global object, and your earlier `var postfix` defines a property on the global object. So `this.postfix` and `postfix` are synonymous in that context.